# Load data from Redux store to React state with Thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

Technology stack: React, Redux, Thunk.

Main task: I need to show on page user info with possibility editing (information inside inputs).

How I do this: User data set inside redux store. After page loading, we send request (with thunk) to take user data from server and write it to redux. Then i should put this data in a inputs with useState().

Problem: "Then i should put this data in a inputs with useState()."

And here is a problems. Re-rendering component problems. My solution: condition, where check is user data loading or not and is state in iput already set.

I think this is doing some more simple.

[My useEffect() where i set state from redux, after redux loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztq8C.png)

Comment: well not everything should be stored in redux if your are using this data for a single component no need for redux and if it's accessible by multiple use redux .

Comment: Your effect is missing a dependency, you are not setting any so it's running every render.

Comment: Yes, I need every render, beacouse in first render I have empty user. When component render, user data is only loading. Just when user put to store, component rerender again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
// your code
}, [])
```

or if you want to be specific

```
useEffect(() => {
// your code
}, [user])
```

then it will only re-render when `user` changes